# Flutter: How to display log in master branch

Tags: ios, dart

I updated my iPhone to iOS 13 and Xcode to 11.

Because of that, it became impossible to build. So I Changed the Flutter SDK branch to master with reference to the following link.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40542

As a result, build and run (flutter run) is now possible. But the log (e.g. print ("log")) that has been seen so far can no longer be seen.

How can I see the log?

Flutter SDK version

```
Flutter 1.10.7-pre.19 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5caad71f1d (27 hours ago) • 2019-09-25 21:49:41 -0400
Engine • revision 739ee77864
Tools • Dart 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.0.0 6c81690c3a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running a `flutter clean` then switching branches to either `stable` or `beta`.

You can do so by running:

```
flutter channel stable (or beta)
```

Once that is finished, you can then run `flutter doctor` to install any missing packages and fix any errors.